# Duvida em select com Where em SQL Server!

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Olá!
Tenho as relações de tabelas acima. Necessito desenvolver uma select que retorne: Os automóveis, de um mesmo fabricante e modelo, que são colocados a venda por mais de uma revendedora. Cheguei ao seguinte código:

```html
select Automoveis.Modelo
from Automoveis
join Garagens as Garagens on Automoveis.codigo = Garagens.cgcRevenda
join Revendedoras as Revendedoras on Revendedoras.cgc = Garagens.codAuto where
```

Esse código ai, retorna todos os automóveis. Agora a dúvida: No where, não faço a menor de ideia do que usar para filtrar os automóveis que foram colocados a venda por mais de um revendedora. Alguém teria alguma ideia de como montar essa parte final?
Grato pela atenção!

Comment: A cláusula `HAVING` com a função de agregação `COUNT` te ajudará.

Comment: Opa. Agradeço pela dica, tentarei implementar!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma possível solução:

```
SELECT A.fabricante, A.modelo, count(distinct R.cgc) as NRevendedoras
FROM Negocios AS N
JOIN Revendedoras AS R on N.cgcRevenda = R.cgc
JOIN Automoveis AS A on N.codAuto = A.codigo
GROUP BY A.fabricante, A.modelo
HAVING count(distinct R.cgc) > 1
```

Onde NRendedores te indica o número de revendedoras (distintas) que vende o mesmo carro (fabricante e modelo).